# Set height of DropdownButtonFormField list

Tags: dart, flutter

In Flutter, `DropdownButtonFormField`'s modal list keeps growing to fill some height limit that seems to be ~90% of the screen (or possibly, and more likely, the `Container` it's in). When it reaches that limit, it becomes scrollable. Is it possible to set that height limit?

Here's the code I'm working with

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title)),
  body: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 5, 5, 5),
      child: Form(
        child: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          children: <Widget>[
            //other widgets here
            DropdownButtonFormField(items: this.dropDownItems),
          ],
        ),
      )),
);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was checking the code of `DropDown` and there is no property to set the height of the `Dialog`, it just fill almost the screen.

I made a small change to the class and you can include to your project if you want:

https://gist.github.com/tudor07/9f886102f3cb2f69314e159ea10572e1

**Usage**

1- Add the file into your project.

2- Import the file with an alias to avoid conflicts.

```
 import 'custom_dropdown.dart' as custom;
```

3- Use the alias in your Widgets related to the DropDown, and add the height property:

```
    Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title)),
      body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 5, 5, 5),
          child: Form(
            child: ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              children: <Widget>[
                //other widgets here
                custom.DropdownButtonFormField(
                height: 200.0,
                items: this.dropDownItems),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
```

4- Don't forget to add the alias also in your `DropdownMenuItem` like this :

```
 custom.DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Text("Sample Tex"),
                value: "any_value",
              ),
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the DropdownButtonFormField class seems to just be incomplete and doesn't behave like other FormFields.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clear with that comment. It worked, thanks! But there's other behaviors that weren't implemented to the class itself (not talking about your custom). Specifically, focus features, which is strange that such an important feature was overlooked.

Comment: There have been some changes to the Flutter code of `DropdownButton` to allow for custom `underline` and `icon`. I added the same change as above to the latest code from Flutter `1.7.8+hotfix.4`: https://gist.github.com/tudor07/9f886102f3cb2f69314e159ea10572e1

Comment: thanks @tudorprodan, you could update my answer adding the changes on the latest version

Comment: It's not showing up centered on the button when I test. It's showing from the top of the screen and then cut at the height specified.

Comment: @diegoveloper You are a Legend!

Comment: Unfortunately, this moves the dialog with list to top of screen, rather it should align itself with DropDownButton.

Comment: the dialog of it is always at the top right of the screen when I limit it's height for some reason

Comment: height property does not exist

Comment: The named parameter 'height' isn't defined.

Answer (score 11):

with this lines you can use `DropdownButtonFormField`like a cheaps:

```
isDense: false,
itemHeight: 60,//what you need for height
```

so your code will be this :

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title)),
  body: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 5, 5, 5),
      child: Form(
        child: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          children: <Widget>[
            //other widgets here
            DropdownButtonFormField(items: this.dropDownItems
               isDense: false,
               itemHeight: 60,//what you need for height
           ),
          ],
        ),
      )),
);
```

Answer (score 5):

I spent over 30 minutes searching for answers!
I simply used the "menuMaxHeight" property of **DropdownButton**

It solved the problem

e.g

```
 child: DropdownButton(
            menuMaxHeight: 300,
```

This works!

Answer (score 3):

```
DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
            child: Container(
              height: // some height,
              padding: // add padding 
              decoration: // add decoration
              child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: ''),  
                // add some function according to you
              ),
            ),
          )
```

**This container decoration is responsible for showing decoration in your dropDown button **

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DropdownButton2 use dropdownMaxHeight: 300, for item list height

```
    DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
   child: DropdownButton2(
      isExpanded: true,  // For Expanded view (cover rest of the container width)
      dropdownMaxHeight: 300,  // For List Height
      hint: ......
      items: ......
   )
)
```