# Flutter: how to set the height of a dropdown in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a dropdown list in my flutter app that has about 30 items in it. When it is selected  I see the values but it takes up whole screen.

How can I control the height of the selected list so that it does not overlay the entire screen (maybe show 10 items with a scroll)

Here is my code

```
 Widget buildCategoryFormField(candidateModel) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("Job category"),
        SizedBox(
          height: 5,
        ),
        FormField(
          builder: (FormFieldState state) {
            return InputDecorator(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ),
                // hintText: "firstname *",
                // labelText: "job category",
                errorText: state.hasError ? state.errorText : null,
                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
              ),
              isEmpty: _selectedjobCategory == '',
              child: new DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                child: new DropdownButton(
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Palette.GREY),
                  value: _selectedjobCategory,
                  isDense: true,
                  onChanged: (String newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      _selectedjobCategory = newValue;
                      state.didChange(newValue);
                    });
                  },
                  items: JOB_CATEGORY.map((String value) {
                    return new DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: value,
                      child: new Text(value),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          validator: (val) => validateJobCategory(val),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set height of DropdownButtonFormField list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53983783/set-height-of-dropdownbuttonformfield-list)

Comment: Have you found the solution here? I've been trying the code you've provided but it seems that I'm missing some essential parts. It would be easy for the community to check your issue if you could provide [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can define `menuMaxHeight` on `DropdownButton` to set maximum height of the expanded dropdown list items.

```dart
Expanded(
  /// LayoutBuilder can be used to fetch the parent widget's dimensions
  child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
    return Center(
      child: DropdownButton<String>(
        /// Set dropdown list max height
        menuMaxHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
        value: dropdownValue,
        items: dropdownItems,
      ),
    );
  }
)
```

[image: Demo]

Adding pagination to the dropdown list is feasible, but this will require creating a custom DropdownButton class. Design-wise, it would be better to break the list into smaller chunks (i.e. by categories) if you'll need to display >50 items in the dropdown.