# Remove default Material design paddings

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design

Basically all Material Design Widget have a default minimum padding, as per their documentation.
Is there a way to remove this padding ? For example, a TextFormField while have its label very close to its content, but I haven't found a way to do the same for a DropDownButton, which is annoying since it break the pattern in a form having TextFormFields and DropDownButtons in it.

Many thanks.

Edit :
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53983783/set-height-of-dropdownbuttonformfield-list) provides the widget I need, which doesn't seem to be well known : DropdownButtonFormField. It adds components like a label, which answers my immediate need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this ?

```
TextField(
   decoration:InputDecoration(
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
      isDense:true,
    ),
```

> EdgeInsetsGeometry contentPadding : The padding for the input decoration's container. [...]

> bool isDense : Whether the InputDecorator.child is part of a dense form (i.e., uses less vertical space). default is false

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the proprieties needed to remove all padding. However DropDownButton doesn't have a 'decoration', so usage of DropdownButtonFormField is required.